# lambda execution role vs aws_iam

Tags: lambda, serverless, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have a serverless application that uses cognito federated users.
For api gateway I use aws_iam authorizer and I provide aws credentials with each request to the api gateway.

now, when my lambda is executed I assumed the role that is assigned to my cognito user will be used, and I will have access to required resources.
But is seems the lambda execution role still needs to have permission to execute those resources.

Do I really need to have 2 roles with the same permission set?
If so what is the point of cognito role?

Answer (score 2):

The IAM credentials you pass to the API Gateway is evaluated at the API Gateway level (If you add permission to the IAM Role granting access to specific endpoint it will be evaluated at **aws_iam_authorizer**).

However, there is a disconnection between the assumed Cognito IAM Role and Lambda execution permission.

The Lambda is executed using the permission of the Role attached to the Lambda function rather the Cognito Identity IAM Role which is assumed to invoke the API.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar question about this. I have a serverless application where I have admin users and regular users.

A lambda function I have queries Dynamo. API Gateway is passing in a user token from which I can retrieve credentials (id, secret, token) and make a call to Dynamo accordingly with the credentials of the user who invoked the API (i.e. an admin or regular user) . My regular users have a role with a policy to only allow them access to their data using 'dynamodb:LeadingKeys' condition. The admin user can query anything in the table.

In this scenario - If I always use these credentials from the token for the dynamo calls, does the Lambda **execution role** still need dynamo permissions? If so, when the dynamo call is made, what credentials is actually using? The Lambda execution role or the credentials from the token?

If I'm retrieving credentials from a token, and using those credentials to query dynamo, I'm not sure why my Lambda execution role needs dynamo privs.

Comment: Maybe I can ask this question more succinctly. I found this helpful article in the meantime: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-user-pool-group/ .  I am not using a user pool authorizer. I'm using a custom token authorizer. However, if I use the credentials contained in the token to do things like read from dynamo, lookup contents in s3, does the lambda execution role need s3 and dynamo rights, or can I get back with the basic lambda execution role if I don't 'use' it to access those services?